# Angular `subscribe` not setting the value when call another method

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-observable

I have a Observable from I am subscribing the data, If I am not set the `setTimeout` I am not able to get the`childnode` of the object. at present I set the timeout. but looking for correct approach of angular.

here is my code :

```
ngOnInit() {
        this.store.appData.subscribe(value => {
            this.appData = value;
            setTimeout(() => this.setLocales(), 1000); //requires this
        } );
    }


    setLocales(){
        console.log( this.appData.hdr.country );
    }
```

error I am getting:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'country' of undefined
    at HeaderComponent.setLocales (header.component.ts:32)
    at SafeSubscriber.eval [as _next] (header.component.ts:26)
    at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrSetError (Subscriber.js:252)
    at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:192)
    at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:131)
    at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:95)
    at BehaviorSubject._subscribe (BehaviorSubject.js:30)
    at BehaviorSubject.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:172)
    at BehaviorSubject.Subject._trySubscribe (Subject.js:98)
    at BehaviorSubject.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:160)

ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: {…}, nodeIndex: 17, nodeDef: {…}, elDef: {…}, elView: {…}}
```

Comment: what is the error if you don't give timeout .?

Comment: getting error as `child` element not get from `undefined`

Comment: @FranklinPious - added all errors from console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

give a type **any** for value or provide corresponding **interface** and provide a check inside the subscribe function.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.store.appData.subscribe((value: any) => {
        if(value && value.hdr) {
        this.appData = value;
        this.setLocales(); 
      }
    } );
}
```

Hope this works.

Comment: No luck. getting same error / issue. I guess this is matter of delay!!

Comment: what is the value when you console.log(value) inside subscribe? Does it get printed twice.?

Comment: getting exact value what i require from service

Comment: Usually delays don't occur when working with Observables. Might be some other issue. Is it possible to provide a plunker?

Comment: Yes, prints 2 times. first as empty second with load of data. I am working with one of the big project can't  i put in plunker. do you have skype?

Comment: So that is the issue. So you could you do a null check inside subscribe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170073/discussion-between-franklin-pious-and-3gwebtrain).

Comment: Yes I done. as like `if(value && value.hdr){
    this.setLocales();
   }`

Comment: Yes works fine. update your answer too.. do you have any idea about this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088002/how-to-access-any-of-the-element-under-a-directive-and-add-events